# Unable to find exact widget using html Generated by widgets

Tags: html, css, gwt, widget, uibinder

I have just started to explore GWT. I am working on layouts using GWT Widgets on mobile views to make it responsive. As client side debugging only allowed in browser I find it difficult to get the exact widget attached in the code

Like this is the widget in code:
 [image]

vpnlScroll instance is used by FLEXPALNEL widget

and the html generated by it is in the form of table:

[image]

When I try to figure out the widget used on that particular area whether what sort of html is generated by it(div or table) using inspect element on the designer tools it does not give me exact reference of the widget used in the code view .Please help me how to counter this also I want to know is GWT designer working in latest version of eclipse to build any user interface more comfortably? Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To identify your widget, you can set the name or id for the widget.

For example,

```
FlexTable myTable = new FlexTable();
myTable.getElement().setAttribute("id", "myTableId");
```

Similarly you can set the name for your widget.